# Updating all Angular components

Tags: angular, npm

Is there a single command that would upgrade all my Angular components?

When I do `ng v` in a VS Code terminal (globally) to see my Angular version, I get this:

[image]

However, when I go into my project's directory, I get the following:

[image]

Is there any way I can upgrade everything to the latest existing versions without having to run commands for every single component?

Comment: You should only update 1 major version at a time, so update to 13 first, then to 14. See: https://update.angular.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update to next major first, so the ideal path from 12 to 14 is via 13.

1. ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13
2. ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14

You might want to commit the changes or use --allow-dirty while upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked as you said. The following three are still on version 12 though. Should I update them individually, or these must already be updated with the commands you provided? `@angular-devkit/architect` 0.1202.17 `@angular-devkit/build-angular` 12.2.17 `@angular-devkit/core` 12.2.17

Comment: It should have updated along with core and cli anyway. Please see if you have any other 3PPs that might require old version and is providing them. Else you can do a clean install of node_modules.